# How to use existing SQL database in my separate project under one solution in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created 2 separate projects under one solution where one project is a class library. I have created an `ADO.NET Entity Model` from my existing database into this. Another project is an ASP.NET MVC web app.

I have used `Individual User Authentication` and wanted to use registration and login facility provided by this.

Now I am unable to use my existing database as this project is creating new database by itself when first runs.

Please guide me how to use existing database. I have given reference to my ASP.NET MVC project. These are my connection strings. Please help me.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LAPTOP-71D4QMB6" 
         connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-71D4QMB6;Initial Catalog=VCAdvertiserDB;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HBDBEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.HBModel.csdl|res://*/Data.HBModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.HBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LAPTOP-71D4QMB6;initial catalog=VCAdvertiserDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Error thrown is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: @marc_s, if you feel that this question is useful to other readers on this site then please up vote this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy the connection string from the app.config of your class library to the web.config of the MVC project. You need to put it in both the root web.config *and* also have to put it in the shared web.config under the shared views folder. That last may not be needed but it also doesn't hurt.
[image]

That worked for me.

Joey

Comment: It does not work into my solution. In last `web.config` there is one auto generated connection string given when project first created.If I remove that string then it gives me the same error. If not then it will create database inside `App_Data`.But the connection string which I added from `App.config` does not do anything. T

Comment: This is defalut `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HotelBooking-20180331101742.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HotelBooking-20180331101742;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Can you please guide me here. I am still not getting the solution.

Comment: if you feel that this question is useful to other readers on this site then please up vote this. Thank you!